# REGEX: How to get the nearest words around the match?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to make an expression that matches lets say 'FINDTHISWORD' + up to 5 words before and after this word? The thing is though that there might be just 0 or 1 word before or after, so it should match 0-5 words + FINDTHISWORD then 0-5 words.

Examples it should match:

```
fdoijfd iudfhiufdh fdhui FINDTHISWORD iduhdfd 
FINDTHISWORD iduhdfd oijfdfd 
doijd FINDTHISWORD
```

Answer (score 15):

You could make use of quantifiers:

```
(\w+ ){0,5}FINDTHISWORD( \w+){0,5}
```

Comment: http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%5Cw%2B%20)%7B0%2C5%7DFINDTHISWORD(%20%5Cw%2B)%7B0%2C5%7D&input=fdoijfd%20iudfhiufdh%20fdhui%20FINDTHISWORD%20iduhdfd%20%0AFINDTHISWORD%20iduhdfd%20oijfdfd%20%0Adoijd%20FINDTHISWORD

Comment: I just added a link, that demonstrated your answer :) +1

Comment: I'd suggest allowing punctuation, incase the input is sunny's last comment, and FINDTHISWORD = "link". Although looking at OP's example data there's no need - more a note for the OP than you devnull.

Comment: @OGHaza In that event one might use, `'([^ ]+ ){0,9}str( [^ ]+){0,9}'` as the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
((?:\p{Xwd}+\P{Xwd}){0,5})\bFINDTHISWORD\b((?:\P{Xwd}\p{Xwd}+){0,5})
```

where

`\p{Xwd}` means any word character unicode compatible
`\P{Xwd}` is the oposite of `\p{Xwd}`

The words before will be in group 1 and the words after in group 2.

Comment: this is what happens when you know too much :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe less elegant than long regexes and quantifiers, but pretty simple to read and understand:

```
grep FINDTHIS file | while read X; do xargs -n1 <<<$X | grep -C5 FINDTHIS|xargs;done
```

Basically, it finds lines containing FINDTHIS and then reads them one at a time into a loop. In the loop, the words in the line are each put on their own line and then I just use regular `grep` with a context of 5 (`-C5`) to get 5 words either side before re-assembling the lines.